# Is there a Collection supertype between Set and Array? If not, how can a function be polymorphic over both Sets and Arrays (for iteration)?

Tags: collections, julia

Is there in Julia a `Collection` type from which both `Set` and `Array` derive ?

I have both:

```
julia> supertype(Array)
DenseArray{T,N} where N where T

julia> supertype(DenseArray)
AbstractArray{T,N} where N where T

julia> supertype(AbstractArray)
Any
```

And:

```
julia> supertype(Set)
AbstractSet{T} where T

julia> supertype(AbstractSet)
Any
```

What I try to achieve is to write function that can take both `Array` or `Set` as argument, because the type of collection doesn't matter as long as I can iterate over it.

```
function(Collection{SomeOtherType} myCollection)
    for elem in myCollection
        doSomeStuff(elem)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to restrict your argument types you could create a [type union](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#Type-Unions-1):

```
julia> ty = Union{AbstractArray,AbstractSet}
Union{AbstractSet, AbstractArray}

julia> f(aarg :: ty) = 5
f (generic function with 1 method)
```

### This will work on both sets and arrays

```
julia> f(1:10)
5
julia> f(rand(10))
5
julia> f(Set([1,2,5]))
5
```

### But not on numbers, for example

```
julia> f(5)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching f(::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  f(::Union{AbstractSet, AbstractArray}) at REPL[2]:1
```

Comment: Excellent ! You can even push further by writing: ```Iterable{N} = Union{AbstractArray{N},AbstractSet{N}}``` which works as intended. Example: ```julia> f(aarg :: Iterable{Float64}) = 5
f (generic function with 1 method) 
julia> f([1.0,2.0,3.0])
5
julia> f([1,2,3])
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching f(::Array{Int64,1})
Closest candidates are:
  f(::Union{AbstractSet{Float64}, AbstractArray{Float64,N} where N})```

Comment: About giving an early error message, I suggest to check the first point in https://white.ucc.asn.au/2020/04/19/Julia-Antipatterns.html . It may not be your use case but it might be useful to see things to avoid.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no `Collection` type, nor is there an `Iterable` one.

In theory, what you ask can be accomplished through traits, which you can read about elsewhere. However, I would argue that you should *not* use traits here, and instead simply refrain from restricting the type of your argument to the function. That is, instead of doing

```
foo(x::Container) = bar(x)
```

, do

```
foo(x) = bar(x)
```

There will be no performance difference.

Comment: Being able to restrict the type is not a question of performance, it's a question of generating error as soon as possible. Because I redefine common operator for my custom types, my functions could execute without error on standard Number or String. But it's not supposed to, and if I use by mistake the wrong type, it can  cause havoc later in the program.

Comment: That's the curse of a dynamic language. You just let it fail there. An iterable in Julia is precisely defined as "something for which `Base.iterate` works".

Comment: I think that your code executing "without error on standard Number or String" is exactly the thing that generic programming enables, and is a reason why code composition and reuse works well in Julia. Shifting perspective to accepting or embracing that which initially seems like a misfeature, is part of the Julia philosophy. Someone (including you yourself) may one day try to use the code for something you did not originally anticipate, and find that it 'just works'.